# How to fix Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform

I want retrieve the data from Firestore Firebase in flutter but display it to the list view and I follow the tutorial from youtube. But it shows error "Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform". I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me how to solve it? Thank you!!

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('TransactionExpense').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    
                        children: [
                          Row(children: [
                            SizedBox(width: 6,),
                            Text(document['category'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                                color: primary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                            ),),
                          ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Row(children: [
                            SizedBox(width: 6,),
                            Text(document['dates'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                                color: primary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                            ),),
                            SizedBox(width: 200,),
                            SizedBox(width: 6,),
                            Text(document['amount'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                                color: primary,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                            ),),
                          ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 8,),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  //_showDeleteDialog(transactionexpense: transactionexpense);
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.delete_forever_outlined,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 6,),
                                    Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                                    ), ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            ),
          );
      }
```

Comment: Can you use `document.get('category');` instead of using `document['category']` in all the places of accessing the document object to get values from firebase collection and revert back?

Comment: Oh yes! it works thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can also catch the stateError and update your variables as you see fit. It removes that red screen 'field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform'.

```
try {
  dynamic nested = document.get(FieldPath(['fieldName']));
} on StateError catch (e) {
  nested = 'null';
}
```