# How to handle if the field I want to access is not in the Firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

```
CollectionReference coursesRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses');

coursesRef
    .orderBy('users', descending: true)
    .limit(6)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
    courses.add(
      ModelCourse(
        authorUid: doc['authorUid'],
        name: doc['name'],
        courseInfo: doc['courseInfo'],
        oldCost: doc['oldCost'],
        newCost: doc['newCost'],
        catName: doc['catName'],
        language: doc['language'],
        color: doc['color'],
        reviews: null,
        path: null,
      ),
    );
  }
});
```

Throws unhandled error that is

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Is there a way to handle this exception? modelCourse will give default value if the input is null.

Is there a way to do it like this

name: doc['name'] ?? null;

If doc['name'] does not work, give null instead.

try&catch didn't work for this case.

I tried

```
try {
   print(doc['name']);
}catch (error){
   print(error);
}
```

it still gives me the same unhandled error.

Comment: Can you try out the answer mentioned in this [StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064217/how-to-fix-bad-state-field-does-not-exist-within-the-documentsnapshotplatform) and see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

```
 final data = doc.data();
 var authorId = data.containsKey("authorId")?data["authorId"]:null;

 //or if you want to acompalish in single line, authrId will be null if not present
 authorId = data.remove("authorId");
```